# PHP var type being reset

Tags: php, types

I'm having some trouble setting data types of a `$_SESSION`-var.

I am using following code to determine if the var needs to be set:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || (isset($_SESSION['login']) && !is_int($_SESSION['login']))){
    $_SESSION['login'] = "5";
    settype($_SESSION['login'], "Integer");
}
```

The code above works perfectly. However, else on my webpage I do queries with that same var, and for some reason these queries cause my code above to run every page load.

For example, using following code:

```
// lots of code
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT something FROM somethingelse WHERE id=:id");
$STH->bindParam(":id",$_SESSION['login']);
exit();
```

the code on top of this page is always run (so `is_int($_SESSION['login'])` is `false`). This code however doesn't:

```
// lots of code
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT something FROM somethingelse WHERE id=:id");
$STH->bindParam(":id",$_SESSION['login'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
exit();
```

But then after `$STH->execute()` it stops working again...

How does this happen? I don't understand, I'm not setting the value to anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general remark: PHP is a [weakly typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). Constantly checking and forcing types is (a bit) like fighting the language. It will never be perfect. Save yourself the effort and work with it instead ;-).

Anyway, `PDOStatement->bindParam()` can be used to fill in the variable on the moment `PDOStatement->execute()` is called. While your query does not seem to have to write to the variable (only read it), PDO may do some resetting of the type anyway. Can you replace your `PDOStatement->bindParam()` with `PDOStatement->bindValue()` (which only takes the value of your variable and leaves the variable itself alone) and see if that fixes things?

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT something FROM somethingelse WHERE id=:id");
$STH->bindValue(":id",$_SESSION['login'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
exit();
```

Comment: Dear lord, `bindValue` seems to work! Thanks! This var is one of two vars I'm checking, just in case something goes wrong with the session, it's the first time I've used `settype()`.